# chainlink data feed prices real-time update

Tags: chainlink

I went through the documentation of Chainlink data feeds and saw we can get the latest price using `latestRoundData()` function from `AggregatorV3Interface`.

The documentation states the price update happens in two threshold, 'Deviation' and 'Heartbeat'. So the deviation for 'ETH/USD' is 0.5% and 1 hour heartbeat time.

But I see Pancakeswap.finance's prediction game uses Chainlink oracle to get latest price of 'BNB/USD' in real-time. But the deviation is not as near as 1% (as mentioned in https://docs.chain.link/docs/binance-smart-chain-addresses/) and it updates price in real-time even less than a minute.

May I know how to update price in real-time?

do we use keepers that keep a watch every second? or is using 'fluxmonitor' (as mentioned here [Timed Chainlink oracle call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91164/timed-chainlink-oracle-call)) a good solution?

or is there a way to get price every time there is a price change (even in cents)?

Comment: Did you ever find an elegant solution to this? I also need a price monitor / keeper, and I'm just starting to research best practices. Pancake-swap's priceprediction game states at the bottom that chainlink prices are updated every 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In the explanation about the Decentralized Data Model, the [Aggregation Parameters](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-decentralized-model/#aggregation-parameters) said:

> "Each aggregation round triggers based on **one of these** parameters. **The first condition** that is met  triggers an update to the data".

The parameters for 'BNB/USD' in Binance Smart Chain are:

- Deviation Threshold: 1%
- Heartbeat Threshold: 1m

So the update are occurring because the off-chain values deviate by more than 1%.

But if the price doesn't change 1% in less than 1 minute, once a minute the price will be updated.

Comment: Hi, but that seems to be not the case at pancakeswap.finance prediction game. Say current BNB/USD price is $455, 1% of $455 is $4.55, but the price change occurs even the price change by $0.10 and that happens everytime in less than 10 = 20 seconds. Checkout https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction.